# how to add numbers in C-shell

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I have a question about C-shell. In my script, I want to automatically add all the numbers and get the total number. How to implement such function in C-shell?
My script is shown below:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set log_list = $1
echo "Search begins now"
foreach subdir(`cat $log_list`)
grep "feature identified" "$subdir" -A1 | grep "ne=" | awk '{print $7}'
echo "done"
end
```

For this script, it will grep the log file "log_list" for keyword "feature identified" and the next line containing keyword "ne=". I care about the number after "ne=", for example ne=140. 
Then the grep output will be like this:

ne=100

ne=115

ne=120

...

There are more than 1K lines of such numbers. Of course I can redirect the grep data to a new file(in Linux). Then copy all the data into Excel spreadsheet to add them up. But I want to do this in the script. And it will make thing easier.
The final result should be like this:

total_ne=335

Do you know how to do this in the C-shell? Thanks!

Comment: unclear what you want as final output. Do you want to discard all of the `ne=xxx` values and only display the total i.e.` tot=335` ? Please update your Q, rather than reply in comments. Good luck.

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to discard all of the "ne=xxx" values and only display the total. I have just updated my question description. Thanks~

Comment: unclear still if you want a grand total, or total per `$subdir`, but `grep "feature identified" "$subdir" -A1|awk '/ne=/{val=$7;sub(/ne=/,"",val);tot+=val}END{print "tot="tot}'` will get you total per subdir. Good luck.

Comment: Suppose we only have one "$subdir", and the grep will search "ne=" for this single "$subdir". After grep function finished, the output will be a list of "ne=xxx", i.e. a column consisting of "ne=xxx". So I think I can remove "foreach" in this script now to avoid further confusing. According to your comment, I think I am saying the latter one, i.e. "total per $subdir".

Comment: unfortunately, `csh` doesn't support arithmetic operations (unlike `bash`). But luckily to you - your `awk` can. your entire script can be replaced by a single `awk` or `perl` line and save you a lot of headache. isn't it better? p.s. I now see that @shellter posted one such line...